# Snapping objects to grid without grid?

Tags: qgis, vector, snapping

Is there a function to snap new or moved vectors to a (user-defined) grid on the map similar to the AutoCAD snapping-function without generation a point/line/polygon-grid over the whole region first?

Specifically, I want to create or move objects in 1 m increments (or multiple) on whole meters.

Comment: Please specify what features you're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled upon what I guess you're looking for:

Go to your layers `properties`, there choose the bottom tab `digitising`, there add a value for `geometry accuracy` (see screenshot).

[image]

The left polygon was digitised with an accuracy of 1 m, the right one with an accuracy of 10 m.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `snap points to grid` tool. Despite its name, it works on polygons by moving its vertices.

[image]