# Is my point feature connected in the correct way?

Tags: qgis, sql

I have line features with a junction like you can see in the screenshot:

[image: junction]

These three lines are different features and now I want to put a point feature in the middle of the junction. If I do so, is the point feature connected to all three lines? Or only with one?

Comment: If all of line feature snap in the same vertex, then yes, the point will touch each of them.

Comment: okay and how can ensure that its the same vertex? I think it should not be a problem if there is no other vertex close right?

Comment: Give it a try and see if you have "duplicates" (well, rather "extremely close points"). If not all is fine, if yes, you can [snap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345649/84870) the vertices to a grid first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Virtual Layer to measure the distances. It will update automatically if you change your point or line layer:

```
select  p.id as pointid, 
        l.id as lineid, 
        st_distance(p.geometry, l.geometry) point_line_distance
from points p
cross join lines l
```

So for example point 1 is intersecting line 1, 2, 3. Even though I snapped point 2 to line 3 it is not intersecting:

| pointid | lineid | point_line_distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 7.151782677346289 |
| 2 | 2 | 7.155708554396829 |
| 2 | 3 | 4.0155625473611995e-10 |
| 3 | 1 | 3.7599431537740893 |
| 3 | 2 | 3.7599431537740893 |
| 3 | 3 | 1.5920007942577854 |

[image]